# DNS ordering when using VPN

Tags: debian, dns, openvpn, nmcli

I'm using Debian 10 and OpenVPN. When I'm connecting to VPN through systemctl it works fine:

```
systemctl start openvpn-client@my_config.int
```

And I have the right ordering of DNS nameservers

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver vpn_dns
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search Home vpn_server
```

But I would like to connect to VPN using `nm-applet`. I added the same config file using nmcli:

`nmcli connection import type openvpn file my_config.ovpn`

After connecting to VPN using nm-applet I got the wrong DNS ordering:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver vpn_dns
search vpn_server Home
```

After googling I tried to modify various options like
`nmcli -p connection modify my_vpn ipv6.dns-priority -42` but it gave no result

systemd-resolved is switched off since I had issues with it before:

```
systemd-resolved.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Network manager config:

```
main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

And I have these entries in my vpn config:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

`resolvconf` package is installed

Comment: This might of interest: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/resolvconf-tutorial.html

Comment: thanks a lot! that helped. turned out resolvconf was in conflict with network manager

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [blissini](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608359/dns-ordering-when-using-vpn#comment1135277_608359) I walked through all service modifying my resolv.conf. Turned out I needed resolvconf for `systemctl start openvpn-client@my_config.int` to work properly (since it doesn't update resolv.conf), but when I tried to use network manager it was in conflict with resolvconf. Deleting this package did the thing